# How to mark a variable as prefab independent?

Tags: unity

I am making a game that has a symmetrical level design. Each player own a portion of the map and each portion is the same. As such, I placed the portion as a prefab so that when I apply the prefab, every other portion gets changed as well.

On the prefab there is a script. This script contains a variable called playerId. I dont want this variable to change to prefab default when I apply the prefab. Is there an attribute tag I can use to do this? As far as I am aware, Unity's transform.position doesnt get affected by the prefab defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such attribute. The special behavior of `transform` in regards to prefabs appears to be hardcoded. But I could think of two workarounds.

1. Abuse the `name` of the game-object to store that information, which is not synchronized between prefab instances either when you apply/revert. A quite hackish solution, though.
2. Move the scripts with the player-Id's to separate game-objects which have no prefab-connection and reference the prefab-instances from them.

Answer (score -2):

Make singletone which will have list of playerIds .When prefab gets spawned ,let script in prefab fetch Playerid from it.

Comment: There is no spawning here. I am using a prefab to synchronise portions of the map to maintain symmetry. These portions are completely similar except that each player has its own player ID and the portions need to know that. But when I click apply under the prefab management, I also synchronise the player ID, which I dont want to happen. The question is whether there is a way to make unity not synchronise this similar to how they dont synchronise `transform.position` and `transform.rotation`.